# p:commandButton not working inside p:dialog

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces, tomcat7

My xhtml page have ui:repeat from which I need to open dialog box that will send the message to the user on which the button clicked. For this I've tried below two approach:

**1.) Move the p:dialog into the separate h:form like below:**

```
<p:dialog id="dialog" showHeader="true" header="Write your message" closable="true" widgetVar="dlg" resizable="false" draggable="true" modal="true" styleClass="job_model_popup" height="300">  
                    <h:form id="dialogForm">
                        <p:panel id="messageFormPanel">   
                            <br />
                            <h:inputTextarea label="Message" styleClass="input_text_field" value="#{MyBean.messageBody}" rows="10" required="true" />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <p:commandButton  actionListener="#{MyBean.myMethod}" value="Send" styleClass="btn" update=":parentForm:growl" oncomplete="handleRequest(xhr, status, args);">
                                <f:param name="_param1" value="#{list['param1Id']}" />
                                <f:param name="_param2" value="#{list['param2Id']}" />                                                                                            
                            </p:commandButton> 
                        </p:panel>
                    </h:form>
                </p:dialog>
```

**I am invoking this dialog box with below button that is in ui:repeat:**

```
<h:form id="parentForm">
                    <ui:repeat id="dataList" var="list" varStatus="status" value="#{MyBean.dataList}">

                        <p:commandLink value="Send Msg" oncomplete="dlg.show();" update=":dialogForm">
                            <f:param value="#{list}" name="list" />
                        </p:commandLink >

                    </ui:repeat>
                </h:form>
```

The problem with this approach is that the **p:commandButton** not firing inside the dialog box. Also the strange thing is that this code was working 2 days back and without any change it stopped working automatically :).

**2.) p:dialog is in same form as ui:repeat :-**

```
<h:form id="parentForm">
                    <ui:repeat id="dataList" var="list" varStatus="status" value="#{MyBean.dataList}">

                        <p:commandLink value="Send Msg" oncomplete="dlg.show();" update=":parentForm:messageFormPanel">
                            <f:param value="#{list}" name="list" />
                        </p:commandLink >

                    </ui:repeat>

                    <p:dialog id="dialog" showHeader="true" header="Write your message" closable="true" widgetVar="dlg" resizable="false" draggable="true" modal="true" styleClass="job_model_popup" height="300">                          
                        <p:panel id="messageFormPanel">   
                            <br />
                            <h:inputTextarea label="Message" styleClass="input_text_field" value="#{MyBean.messageBody}" rows="10" required="true" />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <p:commandButton  actionListener="#{MyBean.myMethod}" value="Send" styleClass="btn" update=":parentForm:growl" oncomplete="handleRequest(xhr, status, args);">
                                <f:param name="_param1" value="#{list['param1Id']}" />
                                <f:param name="_param2" value="#{list['param2Id']}" />                                                                                            
                            </p:commandButton> 
                        </p:panel>                       
                    </p:dialog> 
                </h:form>
```

The problem with this approach is that the p:commandButton is now working but it is not updated with data of row from which the commandLink button clicked. So p:commandButton of p:dialog always have the parameter value from the first row of the dataList.

Please suggest..

Comment: Additional info: MyBean is ViewScoped my method declartion is like : public void myMethod(ActionEvent event) { }

Answer (score 0):

Try another approch (it worked for me)

```
<h:form id="dialogForm">    
<p:dialog id="dialog" showHeader="true" header="Write your message" closable="true" widgetVar="dlg" resizable="false" draggable="true" modal="true" styleClass="job_model_popup" height="300">  

                    <p:panel id="messageFormPanel">   
                        <br />
                        <h:inputTextarea label="Message" styleClass="input_text_field" value="#{MyBean.messageBody}" rows="10" required="true" />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <p:commandButton  actionListener="#{MyBean.myMethod}" value="Send" styleClass="btn" update=":parentForm:growl" oncomplete="handleRequest(xhr, status, args);">
                            <f:param name="_param1" value="#{list['param1Id']}" />
                            <f:param name="_param2" value="#{list['param2Id']}" />                                                                                            
                        </p:commandButton> 
                    </p:panel>

</p:dialog>  
</h:form>
```

Comment: Thanks @jimha for response, I've already tried this (p:dialog inside h:form) but it also not working. The strange thing is that this approach was working for me and also its right now working on Production server with my other code but now on local server its stopped working automatically.

Comment: youn need to add the code that i posted , outsid the principale <h:form> are you doing that ? (because nested forms create some problemes)

Comment: Yes I am not nesting the forms. both h:form are separate forms on the page. As I said earlier I've tried your code as well but no luck :(. Thanks anyways..